# Push single files/commits from local branch to separate remote branch

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

I have a local branch that I would like to branch off of, update just one file, and then push that one file to a separate remote branch. I am getting a git error `error: src refspec remote_branch_name does not match any`.
I need to do this because the remote app uses mongo, and my computer cant install mongo because of various version issues. I have a working remote branch of the app without mongo and this is why I need to push up individual files.
My process is this:

```
git checkout local_working_branch
```

create new branch off of this local branch

```
git checkout -b local_working_branch_clone
```

make updates to one file

```
git add local_file_path
git commit -m "updates to local file"
git push origin remote_branch_name
```

Is it possible to do this in another way?

Comment: You literally cannot push "a file": you can only push *commits*. Every commit contains *every* file (that it contains, that is), so a new commit that changes one file, repeats all 9999 previous files in a 10,000 file repository. You need all the files in the new commit, because if the new commit has just *one* file, it *deletes* 9999 files. (The old commit still has all the files of course: no commit can ever be changed.)

Comment: To change one file, then, you: (1) clone the entire repository as appropriate, so that you now have every file; (2) check out the *last* commit on some branch of theirs by creating, in your repo, a branch (usually with the same name) so that you get the same commit checked out, and thereby have all the files; (3) change the one file, `git add`, and `git commit`; (4) `git push` the resulting commit to send them the one new commit. The fetch and push protocols are smart enough to skip sending the duplicate files, [continued]

Comment: [cont'd] just as a Git commit is smart enough to literally *share* the duplicated files (the files are de-duplicated, in other words). So even though every commit has every file, commits only have the changed files. It all just depends on how you look at it.

Comment: Note that `git push origin <name>` really means: *connect to `origin`, figure out which commits are in my local branch named `<name>` that they don't have, send them those commits, then ask them to set their name `<name>` to remember the same final commit*. That's why you need all their commits: you want to *add* a commit to *their branch*. You don't need to use the same branch names in your repo that they use in theirs, but it helps human sanity to do so, so it's generally wise.